# long to int conversion exception with ASP.NET MVC4 WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(string token)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, token

This seems to be a confusion to me. I'm working with MVC4 Simple membership just to help automate my Account process. all seems ok except when i invoke the WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(string token) and WebSecurity.ResetPassword(string token, string newPassword) methods. both method throw and exception of long to in conversion error when passed with the correct token generated for the user but execute without error and return false when passed with the wrong token. Am i making any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your `UserId` column was created as a `bigint` rather than an `int`. The `WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider` expects that column to be an `int`:

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs#L434

Comment: 2* for that observation. That's definitely where the hitch came from.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert type `long` to `int` because `long` holds 64 bits from memory and  `int` holds 32 bits from memory. Trying to convert `long` to `int` will therefore cause an exception.